# Why can't I make a jQuery pop up when page loads :(

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open up first Fancybox picture automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929787/open-up-first-fancybox-picture-automatically)

I'm having trouble finding a method to make a jQuery FancyBox pop up when the page loads.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#popmessage").fancybox({ 
            'titleShow'     : false,
            'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
            'transitionOut'     : 'fade',
            'overlayColor'      : '#000',
            'overlayOpacity'    : 0.2
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate a click on your DOM:

```
$("#popmessage").click();
```

In jquery style, you could even do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#popmessage").fancybox({ 
            'titleShow'     : false,
            'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
            'transitionOut'     : 'fade',
            'overlayColor'      : '#000',
            'overlayOpacity'    : 0.2
    })
    .click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function(){


        $("#popmessage").fancybox({ 
                    'titleShow'     : false,
                    'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
                    'transitionOut'     : 'fade',
                    'overlayColor'      : '#000',
                    'overlayOpacity'    : 0.2
         })
         $("#popmessage").click();
        })
}
```

Comment: he said he need to show it when the page load read this (load vs ready) http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/

Comment: You're right - although I don't really believe that's what she meant.

Comment: Maybe you're right, but this is what i understood that she wants. Thanks for understanding and for undoing your downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is so small that it's hard to give a proper answer.  Maybe you could post your code on jsFiddle.net or something like that?

Try to break up the problem into smaller pieces.  A js debugger could also be of help diagnosing the actual problem.

1. Is the fancybox javascript loaded?
2. Is the jQuery javascript loaded?
3. can you even do an `alert();` on document ready?

...